# What to save a lot of information into

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm working on a school project which is to create an GPS for an android platform. I'm working in Java.
All the information regarding addresses is saved in text files looking like this 
"139284664 Björlandavägen 26493483 57.7278007 11.9353406".
ID number, name, ref number, latitude, longitude.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know what to save this into in my program. I started out with array lists but then I get Java heap space problems so I moved on to using HashMaps, but then I got the problem that some of the "names" will be the same AND when searching for an address I want to be able to use some sort of `.contain` and not `.equals`. Another requirement we have is that the application has to be offline with only a GPS signal, no internet connection.
Is there any kind of list, map or anything I can use to bypass these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, you want to be using a [database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). It's a bit more complicated than using a container class, but gives much more flexibility (and it's stored persistently, so the data is still there next time you start the app).

Comment: One of the criterias of the GPS is that it will be functional offline with just an gps signal.
And having a local database on the phone was problematic and BIG.
but maybe its possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "having a local database on the phone was problematic and BIG?" Database is the way to go. The best tutorial I found on the net is on youtube from thenewboston: www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEg9OdufXmM
(it goes from 112 to 125 afair)

Comment: Okey i will look into it some more with the databases.

thanks for the tip!

Comment: SQLite uses a text file to represent a database, so you can avoid 80%+ of the headache involved with a full-blown database management system.